# How to scale content by window width with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I'm using the basic window resize code:

```
function onWindowResize() {

    windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}
```

and it resizes the window just fine - but it scales the content based on the height of the window, rather than the width of the window. For the site I'm building it is much more important that the visible width of the content is maintained than the height, but cannot figure out a way to reverse the code to scale based on the width instead of the height.

You can view the problem I'm working on here:http://sunsetfootclinicsign.com/signtest_9.html

I'd appreciate any leads in the right direction! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
geometry.computeBoundingBox();
```

The dimensions can then be computed from geometry.boundingBox.